# Selecting the first and last event per user, per day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a Google Analytics event which fires on my website when certain interactions are made, this may or may not fire for a user in a session, or can fire many times.

I'd like to return results showing the userID and the value of the first and last event label, per day. I have tried to do this with MAX(hits.eventInfo.eventLabel), but when I fact check my results this is not returning the last value for that user in the day as I was expecting.

```
SELECT Date,
customDimension.value AS UserID,
MAX(hits.eventInfo.eventLabel) AS last_value
FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
WHERE parse_date('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) between 
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day) and
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)
AND hits.eventInfo.eventAction = "Value"
AND customDimension.index = 2
GROUP BY Date, UserID
```

For example, the query above returns results where user X has the following MAX() value:

`20180806 User_x 69.96`

But when I look at the details of that users interactions on the day I see:

[image]

Based on this, I would expect to see 79.95 as my MAX() result as it has the highest hit number, instead I seem to have selected a value from somewhere in the middle of the session - how can I adjust my query to ensure I select the last event value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are looking for maximum value of column `colA` while doing GROUP BY - obviously `MAX(colA)` will work

But when you are looking for value in column `colA` based on maximum value in column `colB` - you should use `STRING_AGG(colA ORDER BY colB DESC LIMIT 1)` or similar using ARRAY_AGG()

So, in you case, I think it will be something like below (you should tune it further)

```
STRING_AGG(eventInfo.eventLabel ORDER BY hiNumber DESC LIMIT 1) AS last_value
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case one should work with subqueries on the hits array. This allows full control over what you want to have. I used the example ga data from Google, so labels are different. But I wrote it in a way you can easily modify to fit your needs:

```
SELECT
  date,
  fullvisitorid,
  visitstarttime,
  (SELECT value FROM t.customDimensions WHERE index=2) userId,

  (SELECT 
      --STRUCT(hour, minute, hitNumber, eventinfo.eventlabel) -- for testing, comment out next line  
      eventInfo.eventLabel 
    FROM t.hits 
    WHERE type='EVENT' AND eventInfo.eventAction <> '' -- modify to fit your condition
    ORDER BY hitNumber ASC LIMIT 1
    ) AS firstEventLabel,

  (SELECT
      --STRUCT(hour, minute, hitNumber, eventinfo.eventlabel) -- for testing, comment out next line
      eventInfo.eventLabel 
    FROM t.hits 
    WHERE type='EVENT' AND eventInfo.eventAction <> '' -- modify to fit your condition
    ORDER BY hitNumber DESC LIMIT 1
    ) AS lastEventLabel
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` t
LIMIT 1000 -- for testing
```

Basically, I'm querying events order them by hitNumber ascending or descending and limit to one to only have one result per row. The line with userId also shows how to properly get a custom dimension value.

If you are very new to this concept of working with arrays you can learn all about it here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays

Answer (score 0):

`MAX()` should work.  The one time it would return an unexpected value is if it is operating on a string, not a number.

Does this fix the problem?

```
MAX(CAST(hits.eventInfo.eventLabel as float128)) AS last_value
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, casting as a float means that the MAX() will correctly select the maximum value, but I am looking to select the last value, which is not necessarily the highest as the value can go up or down during a users visit.